# How to pass a string argument having new line to bash file and then passing the complete string to a file?

Tags: string, bash, newline

I have a string as follows:

```
variable="[name]\nabc\n[ip]\n10.12.02\n[name2]\nxyz\n[ip2]\n2.3.536"
"some_bash.sh", :arg=>variable
```

Inside the some_bash.sh i am placing the arguments into file as follows:

```
echo "$1" >> /etc/some_file
```

In the file i get following:

```
[name]
```

and also i get error as 10.12.02: command not found
                        name2: command not found
                        xyz: command not found
                        ip2: command not found

But i want something like following:

```
[name]
abc
[ip]
10.12.02
[name2]
xyz
[ip2]
2.3.536
```

So tell me how shall i do that and have the result as above in a file?

Comment: @Inian updated the question as suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommend using `printf` over `echo` or `echo -e` as it is more portable.

While `POSIX` describes the behaviour of `echo`, in practice it's not as portable as it could be. POSIX documentation for [echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16) even recommends that "*New applications are encouraged to use [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_18) instead of echo.*"

Using `printf` inside the `sampleScript.sh`, to expand the strings, enabling interpretation of escaped sequences(`\n`, `\t`, etc..).

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "$1\n" >> /etc/some_file
```

and pass it your script as

```
./sampleScript.sh "[name]\nabc\n[ip]\n10.12.02\n[name2]\nxyz\n[ip2]\n2.3.536"
```

Comment: you have taken the variable inside the bash script but in my case i need to pass the complete string as an argument to the bash as:sample.sh: args=> "[name]\nabc\n[ip]\n10.12.02\n[name2]\nxyz\n[ip2]\n2.3.536" and inside samle.sh: echo "$1" >> /etc/some_file.

Comment: i removed the space as you suggested.

Comment: as your solution is not according to my problem statement.

Comment: well now its quiet usefull..Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
echo -e "$1" >> /tmp/samplefile
```

`-e` - Enable interpretation of backslash escapes

**Test:**

```
$ bash sample.sh 'some\ntext\nhere'
```

Comment: no its not working for me i did $ bash sample.sh '[some]\ntext\n[here]\nothertext' just got: [some] as output

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
echo "[name]\nabc\n[ip]10.12.02\n[name2]\nxyz\n[ip2]2.3.536"
```

With this line :

```
printf -v variable "[name]\nabc\n[ip]10.12.02\n[name2]\nxyz\n[ip2]2.3.536"
```

The `-v` option of `printf` causes the variable whose name follows to be assigned with the value, and `printf` interprets newlines the way you are writing them.

As a general rule, `printf` will have a more stable behavior across different implementations compare to `echo`, but will require explicit newlines if you need them (instead of the default behavior of `echo` that causes them to be printed automatically).